# javascript - constructor - prototype - __proto__

Tags: javascript

I'm studying javascript and have a trouble to understand the 2nd part in the explanation below. Is it possible for any of you shed me the light on this matter

"The actual prototype of a constructor is function.prototype since constructors are functions. **Its prototype property will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its own prototype**"

Comment: If you understand it, it's actually quite clear.  You'll have to be more specific about which part you don't understand.

Comment: the 2nd part: Its prototype property will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its own prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a series of comparisons will help you figure it out.

> The actual prototype of a constructor is function.prototype since constructors are functions

```
function IamAConstructorFunc() {} // A constructor function

IamAConstructorFunc.constructor // function Function()

IamAConstructorFunc.constructor.prototype // function Empty()

IamAConstructorFunc.constructor.prototype === Function.prototype // True

IamAConstructorFunc.constructor.prototype === Object.prototy // False
```

> Its prototype property will be the prototype of instances created through it

```
var IObj = new IamAConstructorFunc; // Instance of IamAConstructorFunc

IObj.__proto__ === IamAConstructorFunc.prototype // True

IObj.constructor === IamAConstructorFunc // True

IObj instanceof IamAConstructorFunc // True
```

> but is not its own prototype

`IamAConstructorFunc` has a `prototype` but it's not it's own prototype, it's an instance of `Object` and that instance prototype is:

```
IamAConstructorFunc.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype // True
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's an example:

```
function Widget() {
   console.log('Widget constructor invoked');
}


Function.prototype.sayHi = function() { console.log('Function prototype.sayHi invoked'); };

Widget.prototype.sayHi = function() { console.log('Widget prototype.sayHi invoked') };

var w = new Widget();

console.log('Calling w.sayHi()');
w.sayHi();    

console.log('Calling Widget.sayHi()');
Widget.sayHi();
```

This will produce the following log output:

> Widget constructor invoked
>
> Calling w.sayHi()
>
> Widget prototype.sayHi invoked
>
> Calling Widget.sayHi()
>
> Function prototype.sayHi invoked

Calling `w.sayHi()` is calling a method on the Widget object, while calling `Widget.sayHi()` is invoking a method on a function. They have two different prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

That's way too complicated.

A function can be used to create an object.

```
function MyFunc(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

var myObj = new MyFunc(a, b);
```

The function's prototype can be used to create functions that work on the object.

```
MyFunc.prototype.sum = function() {
    return this.a + this.b;
}

var myObj = new MyFunc(2, 3);
var true = (myObj.sum() === (2 + 3));
```

It's probably easier viewing an example.

```js
function Person(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function() {
   return this.first + " " + this.last; 
}

var fred = new Person("Fred", "Flintstone");
var barney = new Person("Barney", "Rubble");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

output.innerHTML += fred.fullName() + "<br>\n";
output.innerHTML += barney.fullName() + "<br>\n";
```

```css
#output {
  color:blue;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the confusion between the `prototype` property of a function and the internal prototype, that every object has.

Every function has a `prototype` property. This property is like any other property of any object. The only thing special about it is, that it will be used as the internal prototype for any object, that is created by that function.

```
function A() {
}

//add property c to public prototype property of A
A.prototype.c = 1;

//create a new instance -> a will get A's prototype property as internal prototype
a = new A();

//a has therefore access to the property c, that was defined earlier
console.log(a.c); //1
```

Since functions are also objects in JavaScript, they also have an internal prototype.

```
function A() {}

//apply is part of A's prototype chain. 
//It's defined on its internal prototype objects,
//which was created by its own constructor, named "Function"
A.apply(this, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement almost drove me crazy but I ended up understanding it. In fact, in JavaScript, a constructor, when created get automatically assigned a property called **prototype**.

This property will be used by all instances created through this constructor as their own prototype and DOES NOT REFER ANYWAY TO the actual prototype of the constructor itself. Actually, the constructor prototype is Function.prototype.

```
var Cat = function() {};
Cat.__proto__ === Function.prototype; // true

var kitty = new Cat;
kitty.__proto__ === Cat.prototype; // true
```

It is normal because the Cat (our constructor) is a Function per se so it derived from Function.prototype. And kitty came out of the new keyword call on Cat so it derived from Cat.prototype.

So in the statement :

> The actual prototype of a constructor is function.prototype since constructors are functions.

**The actual prototype** refers to `__proto__` property of our constructor (Cat).

> Its prototype property will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its own prototype.

**Its prototype property** refers to `.prototype`

Comment: it might be useful to add that `Cat.prototype !== Function.prototype`, and maybe also that, to rephrase in code what you said clearly, `Cat.prototype !== Cat.__proto__`, which might lead one to be careful when using `__proto__`.

Comment: Yes indeed, the key to understand the actual statement in the question was about the difference between **prototype property** and **actual prototype** so yes `Cat.prototype !== Cat.__proto__` worth to be mentioned.